# Using Selenium, ChromeDriver and C# to record and play back a browsing session?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm wondering whether it is possible to record a browsing session using the Selenium IDE and then play it back as a script using C# and ChromeDriver.  Now I know that the IDE can output C# code for the recorded browsing session but can it also output a textual script that can be played back dynamically?  Some sort of XML or Script file that can then be parsed in C# and played back using ChromeDriver?

Answer (score 0):

You can use iMacros extension for Chrome which is similar to Selenium IDE.

Download iMacros for Chrome @ https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to run the script through the ChromeDriver.

Comment: yes. but it will run your steps in chrome as like selenium IDE in Firefox

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to run the steps outside of Selenium, i.e. directly as a script from a C# console application and through the ChromeDriver.  Selenium supports this but only as a compiled test of the recording (you can export the C# code that runs the test).

Comment: Yes, Exactly. I guess i've interpreted question wrongly

Answer (score 0):

now this becomes too easy!
you can get NUnit or XUnit .cs file from recorded test by selenium IDE.
first record your test(macro), then right click on test and choose export from context menu.